# Timestamp formatting in php

Tags: php, date, format, timestamp

Can anyone help me out with the php to get the current timestamp in the format below.

```
2013-05-11 18:00:00
```

My current attempt below:

```
$todaysDate = date('Y-m-d\h:i:s', strtotime('+0 day',time()));
```

Is outputting:

```
2013-05-03h:24:16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formatting:

```
 date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Default value of the date function is current date and time

Answer (score 0):

What's the result if you try without backslash ?

```
$todaysDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('+0 day',time()));
```